# How to append text in a TextArea by delay of 10 seconds in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, textarea

I have this function that pastes data into a `TextArea`  and I want to append text, every iteration in `DisplayChain`, after 10 seconds (just a sample). What should I use?

Here is my code for `DisplayChain`:

```
public void DisplayChain() {    
    for(int i=0;i<chain.size();i++) {
        a.appendText("Block: " + i + "\n");
        a.appendText("Version: " + chain.get(i).getVersion()+ "\n");
        a.appendText("TimeStamp: " + chain.get(i).getTimestamp()+ "\n");
        a.appendText("PreviousHash: " + chain.get(i).getPreviousHash()+ "\n");
        a.appendText("Hash: " + chain.get(i).getHash()+ "\n");
        a.appendText("\n"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: are you tacking about iterations in `DisplayChain` method?

Comment: @thepooran yes i want to delay each iteration on the `DisplayChain`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to use the Thread.sleep method, but you must not call it in the JavaFX application thread.  If you were to do that, you would block the application itself:  there would be no rendering of controls and no responding to user input from the mouse or keyboard, until your sleep call finishes.

This means Thread.sleep cannot be called from an event handler or listener.  To address this, call Thread.sleep from a brand new thread.

However, while Thread.sleep must not be called in the application thread, the opposite is true of JavaFX methods:  they *must* be called from the application thread.  The [Platform.runLater](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method allows you to do that:

```
Runnable task = () -> {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.size(); i++) {
            int index = i;
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                a.appendText("Block: " + index + "\n");
                a.appendText("Version: " + chain.get(index).getVersion()+ "\n");
                a.appendText("TimeStamp: " + chain.get(index).getTimestamp()+ "\n");
                a.appendText("PreviousHash: " + chain.get(index).getPreviousHash()+ "\n");
                a.appendText("Hash: " + chain.get(index).getHash()+ "\n");
                a.appendText("\n"); 
            });

            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};
new Thread(task).start();
```

The reason for `int index = i;` is that local variables cannot be read by other classes, like the anonymous Runnable given to Platform.runLater, unless they are final (or effectively final).

The above code assumes that the `chain` collection does not change.  If it might change while you are reading it, you must make `chain` a thread-safe collection (like [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) or [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)), or implement thread safety yourself, which is probably more complex than you intended the code to be.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Timeline` to repeatedly trigger `appendText` calls for a single "loop iteration":

```
final Timeline timeline = Timeline();

EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        if (i >= chain.size()) {
            // stop thread, if index exceeds chain size
            timeline.stop();
        } else {
            // execute a single "loop iteration"
            a.appendText("Block: " + i + "\n"
                         + "Version: " + chain.get(i).getVersion()+ "\n"
                         + "TimeStamp: " + chain.get(i).getTimestamp()+ "\n"
                         + "PreviousHash: " + chain.get(i).getPreviousHash()+ "\n"
                         + "Hash: " + chain.get(i).getHash()+ "\n"
                         + "\n");
            i++;
        }
    }

};
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), handler));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE); // keep timeline running until handler stops it
timeline.play();
```

**Note:** I recommend extracting `chain.get(i)` to a local variable to avoid accessing the collection multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply `javafx.application.Platform`:

```
new Thread ( () -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep ( delayMs ); // 1000 in this case
        Platform.runLater ( () -> {
            ...
        } );
    } catch ( InterruptedException ie ) { }
} ).start ( );
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well you can add this row

```
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: Sleeping in the application thread will block the application from updating and from receiving user input.